# Why does accessing a python file via a URL yield a 500 error?

Tags: python, webserver

I want a bunch of my friends to download a Python file, so I placed it on my Apache web server and told me friends to go to "http://mydomain.com/someDjangoModels.py".

However, going to "http://mydomain.com/someDjangoModels.py" produces an error 500. Why? The file "mySecretPythonFile.py" is chmodded to 777.

Apache error logs output the following:

```
[Thu Aug 30 12:04:54 2012] [error] [client 71.14.78.236] Premature end of script headers: someDjangoModels.py
[Thu Aug 30 12:05:35 2012] [error] [client 71.14.78.236] Premature end of script headers: someDjangoModels.py
[Thu Aug 30 12:05:50 2012] [error] [client 71.14.78.236] Premature end of script headers: someDjangoModels.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the websever is trying to execute the file rather then download it.

Suggestions:

1. Try chmoding to 666, so that its not considered executable
2. Try changing the extension from .py, so that it doesn't think its python script

Comment: Another option is to disable the `mod_python` extension via `.htacess` for the directory where the files are located.